# single quotes of html attribute automatically get replaced with double quotes

Tags: jquery, django, django-templates, double-quotes, html

If I use a single quoted attribute in a django template like this:

```
<button data-json='{"color":"red"}'>click</button>
```

it automatically gets replaced with:

```
<button data-json="{"color":"red"}">click</button>
```

the enclosing '{}' are transformed into "{}" which makes the attributee unreadable for jQuery.
I already tried

```
{% autoescape off %}
```

without luck.

**EDIT:**

As an experiment I tried something completely without quotes (in template.html):

```
<button data=foo>click</button>
```

which is transformed into (looking at the source code in browser)

```
<button data="foo">click</button>
```

(with quotes).

I know you could rewrite the whole thing as

```
data-json="{'color':'red'}"
```

and then do a javascript `.replace()` to make it valid json - but this seems very ugly to me. How can one stop the magical replacement?